# How to retrieve the yeast locus tag from uniprot via sparql?

Tags: uniprot

Let's say I want to retrieve the yeast-specific identifier for a certain protein, in the example below it will be [P00330](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P00330) which I would like to link to [YOL086C](https://www.yeastgenome.org/locus/S000005446).

When I go to [uniprot's sparql UI](https://sparql.uniprot.org/sparql) and type

```
PREFIX up:<http://purl.uniprot.org/core/> 
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

SELECT *
WHERE
{
    Bind(<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P00330> as ?protein).
    ?protein rdfs:seeAlso ?db .
    ?db up:database <http://purl.uniprot.org/database/SGD> .

}
```

it returns

```
protein db
http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P00330  http://purl.uniprot.org/sgd/S000005446
```

How would I now go on and find the `YOL086C`? When I add the line

```
?db ?p ?o
```

to the query above, I don't see anything that would directly lead me to the identifier.

I also tried to access another database

```
?db2 up:database <http://purl.uniprot.org/database/EuPathDB>
```

but this returns all kind of databases while I am interested only in the `FungiDB`. How could I select this one?

How could I link the two IDs to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, figured it out by looking at the [scheme](http://www.uniprot.org/format/uniprot_rdf) uniprot provides:

```
PREFIX up:<http://purl.uniprot.org/core/> 

SELECT ?protein ?yeast_id
WHERE
{
    Bind(<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P00330> as ?protein).
    ?protein up:encodedBy ?gene .
    ?gene up:locusName ?yeast_id    
}
```

So one starts at the accession number in the middle and then uses the path to the actual `locusName`.

Also the path via the database works fine, I just did not use the `seeAlso` correctly (`protein` was only bound to `db` but not to `db2`, that's why it returned all entries):

```
PREFIX up:<http://purl.uniprot.org/core/> 
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

SELECT ?protein ?db ?db2
WHERE
{
    Bind(<http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P00330> as ?protein).
    ?protein rdfs:seeAlso ?db .
    ?protein rdfs:seeAlso ?db2 .
    ?db up:database <http://purl.uniprot.org/database/SGD> .
    ?db2 up:database <http://purl.uniprot.org/database/EuPathDB>

}
```

This will return the desired output (one would still have to process the `db2` entry, of course):

```
protein db  db2
http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/P00330  http://purl.uniprot.org/sgd/S000005446  http://purl.uniprot.org/eupathdb/FungiDB:YOL086C
```

Comment: I am really happy to see you found your answer! Could we use this as an example query on the sparql endpoint itself?

Comment: @Jerven: feel free to use it, sure! I just updated my answer to show that also the path via the database works fine; I just used it wrong.